# Jet spaces for maps with constraints

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, taylor-series, jets

Lets be in the category $\mathbf{M}$ of smooth finite dimensional manifolds with smooth maps:

Suppose we have the set of all smooth maps $Hom_\mathbf{M}(R^n,M)$ from $R^n$ to a smooth manifold $M$. Taking only the first Taylor-Approximation of any such map, gives us the n-velocity Space $T_nM$, that is a fiber bundle over $M$ and a generalization of $TM$.

Now suppose we just have a subset of $Hom(R^n,M)$ given by some constraints on the maps lets say
$$Hom_\mathbf{M}( R^n,M | constraint_1(f) ... constraint_n(f) )$$.

Does this always gives us a subbundle of $T_nM$?

If not, what should be required to be a subbundle?

Or say it the other way around: What must we proof, to show that the appropriate Jet set is a
subbundle of $T_nM$?

(For my purposes its enough to suppose, that the constraints are of zero-order i.e. don't involve any derivations)

Comment: Could you say a bit more about the nature of the constraints?  Are they algebraic equations in coordinates?

Comment: Yes, they are given as algebraic equations involving the $(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the functions of course.

Comment: ... Things like f(x,x)=f(-x,x). (This is just an example not a definitive required constraint)

Comment: I've never heard the term "n-velocity space" before. What is the precise definition?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the $n$-velocity space is isomorphic to the $n$-fold fiber product of $TM$ over $M$, or equivalently, the tensor product bundle of $TM$ with the trivial vector bundle of rank $n$.

Comment: It is the jet space of smooth maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $M$ evaluated at zero. I.E $J_0(\mathbb{R}^n,M)$

Comment: $J_0(\mathbb{R},M)$ is nothing but the tangential manifold

Comment: OK. Now what is $f$?

Comment: Just to check if I have understood the question correctly... let us say that the constraints are of the form $f(g_i(x))=f(g_j(x))$ with $g_i(0)=0$ for every $i$. (The only hypothesis is the last one: without any structure of $M$, we can only impose things like $f(\textrm{sth})=f(\textrm{sth})$). Let us suppose that $M$ has a transitive group of diffeomorphism; then we can check the condition of subbundle in some point $p$ and then carry the subspace from fiber to fiber. The constraints, in terms of Jacobian matrices in $0$, are $$XG_i=XG_j$$ with $X=\mathrm{Jac}(f)_0$. And this is a subspace.

Comment: Although I still don't understand what the constraints are, I can say that you won't in general get a subbundle unless you assume an appropriate constant rank condition.

Comment: Lets say $p: M \rightarrow N$ is a sujective submersion. Then $J^v_0(\mathbb{R},M):= J_0(Hom(\mathbb{R},M | f(t) \in p^{-1}(x)) \mbox{ for x \in N} )$ is the vertical subbundle of $TM$ relative to the fibration $p$.